# Not able to add .pem cert as a trusted root cert in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I'm using a Shell Script to Copy .pem files to a particular folder in Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I am using the following Approach:

1. I copied my pem file `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`
   [image]
2. I generated crt file from pem file using command `openssl x509 -inform der -in mycert.cer -out mycert.pem`
   [image]
3. I installed the certs in ubuntu machine using command `sudo update-ca-certificates`
   [image]
4. Though the symlinks are created in folder `/etc/ssl/certs` but i can't see mycert.crt entry in file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`
   I can't see the entry even using the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`.

So my doubt is, Is it necessary for a cert to be present in file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` for being a trusted root certificate?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't need to be present in `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` to be trusted.

The file `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` is a means for local admin to override trust policy and disable trust anchors shipped with the OS in `ca-certificates` package without having to manipulate files owned by the package.

Since `/usr/local` tree is already under local admin's control and not owned by `ca-certificates` they can disable trust anchors configured there by just removing the file that they added.

In other words, `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` file is used to add possibility of locally overriding policy regarding trust anchors in `/usr/share/ca-certificates`. Trust anchors in local directory - `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` are not affected by it.

References:

- [source of update-ca-certificates](https://sources.debian.org/src/ca-certificates/20190110/sbin/update-ca-certificates/)
- [source of the postinst script](https://sources.debian.org/src/ca-certificates/20190110/debian/ca-certificates.postinst/)